# How can i get all the prediction probability value?

Tags: python, keras

I'm doing stock prediction using keras.While prediction i get only one possible result.I need to view all the probability value for example,
    input 100 120 100 120, target while training 100
    while prediction if i give the same input it returns 120 as a output
    So that,is there any possibility of view prediction probability value?

Comment: You should provide some example code.

Comment: I assume we're talking about regression here?

Answer (score 0):

What i've done is include a randomized feature. This way the network won't be purely deterministic